# how to change the title of my github page from https//name.github.io to title of my choice

Tags: html, github-pages

[image]

I have tried using `<title>` tag in "default.html" but it just adds a title in my page and doesn't change my browser tab

theme : jekyll hack

Comment: Do you mean for domain or?

Comment: i don't want to change the domain name just the visible browser title

Comment: `<title>` is the correct tag to use, but you have to add it into the `<head>` section.

Comment: i must have did something wrong before it works now ty @Progman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<title> your_title </title>` in the head section of default.html

default.html is located under "your-github-domain/_layouts"